# Rails 4 How to convert multiple email notifications into a batch email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have an app working whereby a user can elect to receive email notifications if there is an update to a page that belongs to him.  I've got it working great, EXCEPT, if there are multiple pages with pending updates (I change status to pending when an update is made) then the user might eventually get SLAMMED with several emails - one per page that belongs to him/her.

It took me a while to get this going originally, but now I'm at a loss for how I might send all updates that belong to a user in one batch email whenever the task is run (currently once a day).

Here is the task:

```
task :notify_user => :environment do
 ProductPageUpdate.where(status: 'pending').each do |page_update|
  PageUpdate.user_notification(page_update).deliver!
  page_update.update_attribute(:status, 'notified')
 end
end
```

This sends my page_update/user_notification.html.erb email which simply includes a link back to the corresponding page:

```
  <h2>Your page has been updated!</h2>
  <p><%= link_to @page_update.page.name, page_url(@page_update.page) %></p>
```

Any simple ideas for how to send all queued up pending updates that belong to a user in one email instead of many at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In task:

```
   task :notify_user => :environment do
      page_updates = ProductPageUpdate.where(status: 'pending')
      PageUpdate.user_notification(page_updates).deliver!
      page_updates.each do |page_update|
        page_update.update_attribute(:status, 'notified')
      end
    end
```

In mailer template:

```
 <% @page_updates.each do |page_update|%>
 <p><%= link_to page_update.page.name, page_url(@page_update.page) %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I knew it was something along those lines - just moving a few things around.  Thanks, I'll use that!!